Supabase Assign Custom Auth Role into Users
I know that I can create my own custom role by creating another table that contains roles. But I discovered that I can create my own custom role built-in inside the Supabase Database, which is easier whenever I want to create some RLS based on users role from the dropdown menu, so I don't have to create a query to validate the role of the users.
Here is my custom Roles:

And this is the dropdown menu I mentioned earlier

The question is, how can I create users and assign their roles? I have tried these JSON bodies:
{
    "email":"testeriz@gmail.com",
    "password":"12345678",
    "data": {
        "username":"testeriz",
        "role":"owner"
    }
}

and
{
    "email":"msamangsumamang@gmail.com",
    "password":"12345678",
    "role":"owner"
    "data": {
        "username":"Miming"
    }
}

But the result is always authenticated like this:

